# Ajax unobtrusive login form not functioning as expected

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I am learning to use Ajax in my mvc application. I am trying to get my login to work without having to change the page as my login form will be within the navbar with many other ajax forms. I could really use some help as I am not sure how to bind it to the loginmodel either because it never hits my controller. Thanks in advance for any tips you have.

[image]

View

```
<section id ="loginForm">
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
            UpdateTargetId = "loginSection",
        }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "input-sm form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-sm-3 control-label" })
            <div class="col-sm-9">
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "input-sm form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <div class="checkbox pull-right">
                    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
                <button class="btn btn-default pull-right" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-unlock-alt"></i> Sign in</button>
                <i id="ajax-loader" class="fa fa-spinner fa-pulse" style="display:none"></i>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
</section>
```

Controller

```
//AccountController
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public async Task<ActionResult> Login(LoginViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var result = await SignInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, shouldLockout: false);
    switch (result)
    {
        case SignInStatus.Success:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.LockedOut:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.RequiresVerification:
            return View("Lockout");
        case SignInStatus.Failure:
        default:
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Invalid login attempt.");
            return View(model);
    }
}
```

Model

```
public class LoginViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
    public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: It's never hitting the controller. Gives me a 404 error saying not found

Comment: `Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account", ..` should hit the `Login()` method in `AccountController`. Do you have areas? Also check the generated html for the `<form>` tag.

Comment: Yes the code is in the above

Comment: There is nothing in _the code above_ that answers either of my queries. (1) Show the actual html generated in the view - i.e. inspect the page source. (2) Are you using areas - if so, what is the area name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve my problem by noticing my post was actually going to Home/Login instead of Account/login even though i gave the string "Account" to ajax. the following fixed my issue.

```
new {controller="Account"},
```

instead of

```
"Account"
```

within

```
 @using (Ajax.BeginForm("Login", "Account",
        new AjaxOptions
        {
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            LoadingElementId = "ajax-loader",
            UpdateTargetId = "loginSection",
        }, new { @class = "form-horizontal" }))
    {
      ...
    }
```